# Stop people pressing a button as an alert comes up

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating/created the following here: http://jsfiddle.net/Tomzen/hu720awa/
However a problem pops up every now and then, if a user clicks the "Click!" button as the alert comes up (which tells you to stop clicking), the timer will restart and the results will be reset (You'll see if you use it)

I cannot figure out a workaround except for creating a timer which disables pressing the button a few milliseconds before the alert pops up.
Could someone please have a look and see if they've seen this sort of thing happen before?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
score = 0;
stop = 0;
$("#test").html("Score: " + score + "<br>Average: 0<br>You have 5 seconds to click as fast as you can. Your time will start on the first click.");
$("counting").html("test");

$("#button").click(function () {
    score = score + 1;
    average = score / 5;
    $("#test").html("Score: " + score + "<br>Average: " + average + " cps.<br>You have 5 seconds to click as fast as you can.");
    startTimer();
});

function startTimer() {
    if (stop === 0) {
        stop = stop + 1;
        var counter = 0;
        var interval = setInterval(function () {
            counter++;
            display = 5 - counter;
            $("#button").html("CLICK! (" + display + " secs)");
            if (counter == 5) {
                alert("It's been 5 seconds, stop clicking now.");
                clearInterval(interval);
                stop = 0;
                endscore = score;
                score = 0;
                $("#test").html("You clicked " + endscore + " times, in 5 seconds.<br>Your average click speed was " + average + " clicks per second.<br>Start clicking again to retry and get a better score!");
                $("#button").html("CLICK! (5 secs)");
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
}
});
```

Code is JQuery and JS, also uses HTML and CSS found on the JSFiddle, and there may be useless code.

Comment: The person clicks it as many times as they can within 5 seconds, then the alert goes off to tell them to stop clicking (when the 5 seconds is up)

Comment: Could not reproduce  _" if a user clicks the "Click!" button as the alert comes up (which tells you to stop clicking), the timer will restart and the results will be reset"_

Comment: Try getting elapsed time and then disable few milliseconds before!!

Comment: Got 9cps but couldn't reproduce the issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your issue. Just before the timer reaches 0, click and hold the mouse key down on the button. The alert will come up. Hit enter on the keyboard to dismiss the alert box. Then release the mouse. (This was an old-school way to get around right-click disabling scripts before the dev console.) Another click will register and the counter will start again.

To prevent this, change

```
$("#button").click(function () {
```

to

```
$("#button").on("mousedown", function () {
```

to ignore mouse up actions associated with click.

You have `stop = 0;` after the `alert()`, so there is no way another click as the alert comes up will trigger the logic in `if (stop === 0) {`, only the `mouseup` event after the alert is dismissed will allow this to happen.

**Demo:** [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ayn33c1o/)